# Given a set of integers and target, find all subsets of size k such that sum of elements of each subset equals target

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, np-hard

I am trying to solve below problem

Given a set of integers A, and target integer, find all subsets of size k such that sum of elements of subset equals target.

One approach could be enumerating all subsets of size k and checking whether sum equals to target. However this takes O(n!) time. I am trying to find an algorithm that takes less time than O(n^3).

Other approach I tried is to solve using dynamic programming.

1. Construct a 3D table of size (k, n+1, target+1) and initialize all
   elements to false.
2. Base case : m[0][0][0] = true
3. Fill all the elements in bottom up fashion using below equation
   m[i][j][k] = m[i-1][j][k] OR m[i-1][j-1][k-A[k]]
4. Reconstruct the solution in top-down manner.

Anybody can suggest an algorithm that is better in time and space comlexity than this?

Comment: (What is $a$ in $-a[k]$?)

Comment: a is array of integers

Comment: Do you really mean find (aka enumerate) or count?

Comment: You cannot do in less than $n \choose k$, which in particular means you wont find an algorithm of $O(n^3)$ for any $k>3$. To see that take a look at the example that will have as many such subsets as possible: $A$ consists only of $1$'s, and the target is exactly $k$

Comment: @tstanisl not just count, but find elements of all such subsets.

Comment: Besides, no polynomial-time algorithm is even able to decide whether there is at least one such subset, unless $P =NP$.